# How to handle paging & sorting efficiently through WCF RIA service using dataset while dealing huge tables

Tags: .net, silverlight

I have successfully created a WCF RIA service by creating DomainService class and accessing the oracle database using ADO.NET. However creating a domainservice using ADO.NET seems to have limitations when compared to creating a domainservice using entity framework in terms of efficient sorting, paging of huge tables(more than 5 million records). Is there any way to implement efficient paging and sorting using ADO.NET? If so, can anyone share some code?

I want to databind the domainservice to silverlight datagrid and expecting paging/sorting on datagrid.

Comment: What exactly to you mean by sorting/paging? Are you simply looking to move the sorting/paging logic from the client to the server? If so, here is an article that might help you:
http://tinyurl.com/ycnnzbm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Henrik Thanks for the link.

For the sake of others who has same/similar type of scenario,Here there is another [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/27/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-9-dataset.aspx) that is more specific to my question i.e. using ADO.NET (& eventually dataset)